# How much should I expect to pay for a 3 hour "longtail" boat ride around Ko Phi Phi Island?

Tags: thailand, islands, price, phi-phi

Many guides offer boat rides in their "longtail" wooden boats, and many even use the same price deck, which quotes THB 1500 for a 3 hour boat ride around Ko Phi Phi Le. Note this is for a "private" ride which means just 1 or 2 people in the boat (not a speedboat).

With careful negotiation, how much could I expect to pay? Are there places on the island where I can get a much better deal for a 3 hour private boat ride?

Comment: How western do you look? And do you speak any Thai?

Comment: European (see photo), and no Thai outside of sawasdee.

Comment: Lookout for scammers. I once had to pay 4000 THB for a speedboat in Floating Market.

Comment: @KevinBurke That actually sounds pretty reasonable. You might be able to get it down to ~1000, but unless you're Thai good luck!

Answer (score 4):

[Wiki Voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ko_Phi_Phi) quotes it around 1200 TBH:

> Phi Phi officially has no motorised transport, though there are a few
>   motorcycles with sidecars, usually used for goods and construction
>   material transport. Transport on land is by foot or bicycle, but in
>   the populated areas of Ton Sai, nowhere is more than about a ten
>   minutes walk from anywhere else. Longtail boats sail between all
>   beaches. On Phi Phi Don, you can also walk to any beach. From Ton Sai
>   to Long Beach, expect to pay 40 baht/person in the afternoon, at least
>   80 baht at night. To have a complete boat to yourself, expect to pay
>   at least 100 baht.
>
> Wheelbarrows are used to transport goods, including your luggage if
>   you like. Expect free transport from the pier to your room, but not
>   necessarily in the opposite direction.
>
> The most common ways to get around on Ko Phi Phi are by foot and by
>   longtail. As with most everything in an area like this, the price for
>   longtail boats is a negotiation. Hint: Take some foam earplugs for the
>   longtail boat rides. It's a fun ride but the engines are loud and
>   after 45 minutes it can get to you. Negotiating for longtail boats is
>   usually done according to where you want to go and how many hours you
>   want the trip to last. As an example, 1,200 baht for a 6-hour outing
>   to Ko Phi Phi Leh and Ton Sai Bay from the Holiday Inn Resort.

I used this website a few times to have an idea of the different prices while I was in Thailand and it was pretty accurate.
While I was there I paid a bit more around 1300 TBH.

But as Gagravarr said the prices can differ if you look and/or speak Thai.

I hope it helped you and have a good trip!

Comment: That says 1200 for a 6 hour journey. I assume six hours would be more expensive than a 3 hour journey, which is why I thought it was unrealistic.

Comment: Yes indeed, but don't expect it to be half of the 6h price.